# Is it posible if a Java application connects to MQ Client, not MQ Server?

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I'm newbie in IBM Websphere MQ.

Now, I have

- Server **A** runs **MQ Server**
- Server **B** connects to Server A as **MQ Client** (using Environment variable **MQSERVER**)

I already finished Java application (located at Server B) that connects directly to **MQ Server** at Server **A**. But my boss still want this Java application only connect locally to MQ Client and then MQ Client connect to MQ Server.

Is it a little bit funny because my Java application is already a MQ Client?

Comment: Indeed, your Java application uses the MQ Java/JMS client to connect to MQ server. MQ client is set of libraries (DLLs/Jars/.so) and headers files and you use them to build MQ applications.

Comment: Yes, I think so. You are right.

Comment: Upon which machine does your Java application run?

Comment: I run Java Application on Server B, and it connect to Server A by IP and queue listening port

Answer (score 1):

You can read this, it explains the client and how to use it:

http://www-01.ibm.com/software/integration/wmq/clients/

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24037500

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24032744

Comment: Ah yes, thank you, but the problem is a little funny if my Java application have to connect with MQ Client.
It likes your application must connect to a SQL Client (HeidiSQL or Sequel Pro, ...) to excute your SQL query.